# How to fix the blank page after click Save / Save And Close in Joomla 2.5.16

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I'm having a problem when I try to save something in Joomla!2.5.16

When I click in Save or Save & Close a blank page appears. I press F5 or Enter to return the last page. The strange thing is the changes are saved, but I always have to press F5 or enter to go back.

I've tried to debug, but it doesn't work.

Can you help me? I'll appreciate.

P.s: its my first post here, sorry if I made some mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily set `Site -> Global Configuration -> Server -> Error Reporting` to "Maximum" to see if you can generate a more meaningful error message.

Try increasing the PHP `memory_limit` via `php.ini`, `.htaccess`, cPanel or similar.

Answer (score 1):

also check if your anti virus web shield is on, i know it sounds strange but i was having a similar problem with avast web shield and joomla , so during your admin work shut it off and then turn it back on.